# Simply correcting OLS standard error in time series context

Tags: time-series, least-squares, econometrics, autocorrelation, standard-error

In microeconometrics, [it is sometimes advised to always use heteroscedasticity-robust standard error](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/452/always-report-robust-white-standard-errors) (instead of testing for heteroscedasticity and using generalized or weighted least squares or something else). This is the case because heteroscedasticity or autocorrelation / serial correlation affects the [interval estimates only](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/143889/9866) but not the point estimates.

If I am applying OLS in a time series context,

1. is there a similar advise to simply address autocorrelation (even if disputed)?
2. does it depend on whether the time series is short or long (small vs large T)?

I asked [a similar question before](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/440833/overview-standard-error-correction-in-time-series-panel-literature), but this one is much more specific to the time series context, and I am happy even with suggestions not every agrees with.

Comment: [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=clothes+diebold) are some threads citing Diebold who is against HAC robust standard errors.