# Mixed model or ANOVA on differences in pre-post design

Tags: r, anova, mixed-model, heteroscedasticity, diagnostic

I want to analyse the effect of different treatment types (`control, treatment1, ..., treatment4`) on the surface of specimens made of certain materials (`plastic, metal`). The undamaged area of the surface is measured `before` and `after` the treatment.

According to this design I specified a mixed model using lme4 as follows:

```
require("lme4")
data <- read.csv("http://pastebin.com/raw/G4D8dh1f")
mm1  <- lmer(undamaged_area ~ time*material*treatment + (1|specimen_id), data)
```

**Questions:**

1. Is the mixed model the optimal choice in this case? I found some hints that an ANCOVA (something like `lm(undamaged_area_after ~ material*treatment + undamaged_area_before, data)`) might be an alternative approach.

   A closer look on the diagnostic plots of the mixed model makes me very suspicious:

   ```
   plot(mm1); require("lattice"); qqmath(mm1)
   ```

   [image: diagnostic plots]
2. Does the plots actually indicate a violation of model assumptions? Does the strange pattern come from a misspecification of the model?

**Progress after [donlelek's answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/208463/112794) (=mixed model not required):**

Just to be clear: The treatments were measured in different pieces of metal/plastic. So every piece is exactly measured twice - before and after the treatment. Thus, we are aiming for the ANOVA on damage, I guess. I had the impression to lose informations by just substracting the pre-post values. I did further research in the literature (with my limited knowledge in statistics). But according to ["Pretest-posttest designs and measurement of
change"](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/b764/e331525ec9ba814b51ee890aea7f663e175d.pdf) the use of such gain scores seems to be ok:

> "First, contrary to the
>   traditional misconception, the reliability of gain scores is high in many practical situations, particularly when the pre- and posttest scores do not have equal variance and equal reliability."

so we have the following model:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

data <- read.csv("http://pastebin.com/raw/G4D8dh1f")    
data_wide  <- data %>% 
  spread(time, undamaged_area) %>% 
  separate(specimen_id, c("mat", "id", "tx")) %>% 
  mutate(damage = before - after, 
         unique_id = paste(mat, id, sep = "_")) %>% 
  select(-mat, -tx, -id)

# model for full factorial with replications
mm2  <- lm(damage ~ material * treatment , data = data_wide)
```

The variance problem still remains. Confirmed by Levene's test:

```
library(car)
leveneTest(damage ~ material * treatment, data_wide)

# Levene's Test for Homogeneity of Variance (center = median)
#       Df F value    Pr(>F)    
# group  9  4.8619 2.646e-05 ***
#       90                      
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Following the link suggested by donlelek I found different approaches for [anovas with heteroskedastic data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/91872/alternatives-to-one-way-anova-for-heteroskedastic-data/91881#91881). I tried to stabilize the variance by using log-transformation. Then Levene's test says that heterogeneity of the variance diappears:

```
data_wide <- within(data_wide, log_damage <- log(damage+1))
leveneTest(log_damage ~ material * treatment, data_wide)

# Levene's Test for Homogeneity of Variance (center = median)
#       Df F value Pr(>F)
# group  9  0.6916 0.7147
#       90
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

The diagnostic plots seems not to be as weird as the previous ones (see [donlelek's answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/208463/112794)):

```
mm3 <- lm(log_damage ~ material * treatment, data_wide)
plot(fitted(mm3), residuals(mm3, type = "pearson"))
qqnorm(residuals(mm3, type = "pearson"))
```

[image]

The anova table gives the following output:

```
anova(mm3)

# Analysis of Variance Table
#
# Response: log_damage
#                    Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
# material            1  0.436  0.4362  0.7462      0.39    
# treatment           4 83.652 20.9129 35.7786 < 2.2e-16 ***
# material:treatment  4 20.213  5.0532  8.6452 5.966e-06 ***
# Residuals          90 52.606  0.5845                      
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Just for double checking:

The `Anova` function from `car` package offers an option for heteroscedasticity correction. Interestingly, this function generates a roughly similar table for the "non-transformed" `mm2`:

```
Anova(mm2, white.adjust=TRUE)

# Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II tests)
# 
# Response: damage
#                    Df       F    Pr(>F)    
# material            1  1.4251    0.2357    
# treatment           4 28.2422 3.329e-15 ***
# material:treatment  4  9.5739 1.701e-06 ***
# Residuals          90                      
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

**New questions:**

This double check gives me more confidence in the results. But do you think that the log-transformation is a reasonable approach? Can I trust the model now?

Answer (score 3):

I would say that first you have to think about your outcome. As I understand it you are measuring the area in the same piece of metal before and after the treatment, I think the outcome in this case should be the difference between the two measurements, the `damage`.

In your question, you also don't specify whether the treatments were measured in the same piece of metal/plastic or in different pieces of metal/plastic. Answering your first question, a mixed model would be more convenient for the former while the latter would not require a specification of hierarchy and a linear model or ANOVA would be ok.

I modified your dataset to get the `before` and `after` measurements available to get the difference (`damage`) and fitted 2 models, one with mixed effects and one with fixed effects only.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

data_wide  <- data %>% 
  spread(time, undamaged_area) %>% 
  separate(specimen_id, c("mat", "id", "tx")) %>% 
  mutate(damage = before - after, 
         unique_id = paste(mat, id, sep = "_")) %>% 
  select(-mat, -tx, -id)

# model for full factorial with replications
mm2  <- lm(damage ~ material * treatment , data = data_wide)

# model with mixed effects
mm3 <- lmer(damage ~ material * treatment + (1 | unique_id), data = data_wide)

> anova(mm2)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: damage
                   Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
material            1   9030  9029.8 17.4707 6.750e-05 ***
treatment           4  46676 11669.1 22.5771 6.194e-13 ***
material:treatment  4  12880  3219.9  6.2298 0.0001799 ***
Residuals          90  46517   516.9                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

> anova(mm3)
Analysis of Variance Table
                   Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value
material            1   6370  6369.6 13.3532
treatment           4  46676 11669.1 24.4629
material:treatment  4  12880  3219.9  6.7502
```

You can fit these models and explore them to check where the differences are, but both models have the same problem as your original model, the residuals.

```
qqnorm(residuals(mm2, type = "pearson"))
```

[image: qqplot]

Normality looks not too bad.

```
plot(fitted(mm2), residuals(mm2, type = "pearson"))
```

[image: residuals]

But residuals against the fitted values look weird, I think in textbooks this distribution of the residuals is described as a shotgun blast and indicates a misspecification in the model.

I'm not sure how to fix your model but a quick exploration of the data seems to indicate that you have very unequal variances within your treatments.

```
# summarize means and variaces by group
data_wide %>%
  group_by(material, treatment) %>% 
  summarise(avg_dmg  = mean(damage), 
            variance = var(damage))


|material |treatment  | avg_dmg| variance|
|:--------|:----------|-------:|--------:|
|metal    |control    |    23.9|    238.1|
|metal    |treatment1 |    38.0|    924.8|
|metal    |treatment2 |     1.9|      9.3|
|metal    |treatment3 |    92.0|   1488.9|
|metal    |treatment4 |    64.4|   1395.5|
|plastic  |control    |     8.0|     54.9|
|plastic  |treatment1 |    30.3|    281.9|
|plastic  |treatment2 |     9.7|     36.7|
|plastic  |treatment3 |    31.5|    362.1|
|plastic  |treatment4 |    45.7|    376.4|
```

Some advice on how to deal with this is offered in [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56971/alternative-to-one-way-anova-unequal-variance). I hope this helps to solve your problem.

UPDATE: Daniel solved his problem by log transforming the outcome, check his updated analysis.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments! Sorry for the confusion: The treatments were measured in different pieces of metal/plastic. I edited my post above and added my progress according to your suggestions (ANOVA on damage). I would be very happy about your remarks and comments!

Comment: Hi @Daniel, great job spotting the transformation issue, sorry I missed that. I guess now you should explore a couple of outliers you have there but I would say your model is good to go! Cheers