# Importance of Equal Error Variances in Mixed ANOVA

Tags: variance, anova

Depending on the textbook I use, sometimes the equality of error variances in a mixed ANOVA is considered an assumption of the model and sometimes not.  I did a literature search, but found nothing.

Does the mixed ANOVA assume equal error variances, is it robust to a violation of this assumption or can this assumption be ignored all together?

Comment: You should add references to the texts you used!

Comment: Equality of variances is an assumption of ANOVA. However, it is said that for practical purposes differences of variances up to ten fold don't invalidate ANOVA results. I'm sorry that I can't point to any reference.

Comment: The answer to http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56971/alternative-to-one-way-anova-unequal-variance may be useful.