How to dealing with altered mean rankings after transformation in ANOVA?
I performed an ANOVA on my dataset, which includes 5 treatments with a sample size of 30. Since the data was not homoscedastic, I applied a Box-Cox transformation. After the transformation, I conducted an SNK multiple comparison test. However, the transformation significantly altered the magnitude of the data, causing some means that were higher in the original data to become intermediate or even lower. As a result, when I applied the letters to indicate differences between means in my table, they no longer made sense in the context of the original data. This table needs to be presented in a scientific paper, and in its current form, it may confuse the readers. Should I proceed by applying the SNK test to the original data, or is there a better way to proceed with the statistical test?

You really need to tell us the specifics of the situation, what are the five different treatments, what are being measured? But maybe you are really interested in the means on the original scale, not the transformed scale? Then use an anova test that does not assume equal variances

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56971/alternative-to-one-way-anova-unequal-variance

You may be interested in reading the following post https://www.slideshare.net/slideshow/why-are-data-transformations-a-bad-choice-in-statistics/239588183 This directly addresses your observation "the transformation significantly altered the magnitude of the data". If you can interpret the results in the transformed space (which I doubt for Box-Cox), then all is fine. Otherwise, indeed, you have a problem... And given that your samples sizes are balanced, ANOVA does not require homoscedasticity; so you do not need to transform.
